# Obtaining Ivy metadata for a jar

Tags: java, scala, ivy

Given a reference to a jar in `~/.ivy2/cache`, how can the Ivy metadata about the corresponding Ivy package be obtained?

This is as far as I could get, for `jackson-core-2.5.4.jar`. I wrote this in Scala, but a Java solution would be ok too. I believe that if the error shown in the code was fixed, the answer I am looking for would likely be found in the returned `ResolveReport`.

```
object PoisonIvy extends App {
  import java.net.URL
  import java.nio.file.{Path, Paths}
  import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
  import org.apache.ivy.Ivy
  import org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport
  import org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveOptions
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val confs = Array("default")
  val resolveOptions = new ResolveOptions()
    .setDownload(false)
    .setTransitive(true)
    .setConfs(confs)

  val ivy: Ivy = Ivy.newInstance()
  val ivyHome: Path = Paths.get(sys.props.getOrElse("ivy.home", sys.props("user.home") + "/.ivy2"))

  FileUtils.listFiles(ivyHome.toFile, Array("jar"), true).asScala.find { file =>
    file.getName == "jackson-core-2.5.4.jar"
  }.foreach { file =>
    val url: URL = file.toURI.toURL

    // [Fatal Error] jackson-core-2.5.4.jar:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    val resolveReport2: ResolveReport = ivy.getResolveEngine.resolve(url)
    println(resolveReport2)

    // [Fatal Error] jackson-core-2.5.4.jar:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    val resolveReport1: ResolveReport = ivy.resolve(url, resolveOptions)
    println(resolveReport1)
  }
}
```

I used these dependencies in `build.sbt`:

```
"org.apache.ivy" % "ivy" % "2.4.0"
"commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.6"
```

I made an SBT project on GitHub [with this code](https://github.com/mslinn/ivy-fun/blob/master/src/main/scala/Main.scala#L52-L66) to play with.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood the question - you're talking about metada that is in ivy descriptor (that is the ivy.xml file) ?

Comment: @cantSleepNow Seems that the Ivy Java library uses the info in the xml files, possibly along with other information. The code that I show attempts to obtain a resolveReport for every dependency in ~/.ivy2/cache, but it fails.

Comment: Ivy uses only ivy.xmls (descriptors), also some properties files in cache. But still, I didn't understand if you need to obtain the info in the descriptors, or metadata of the jar (like manifest)?

Comment: Actually, I just want to associate the jar with the java doc/Scala doc URL

Comment: Ok so javadoc. That is done by ivy. Javadoc first needs to be in the cache, and that is only the case if you have resolved all types of artifacts. In the ivy.xml there is attribute called type, so you just need the one with the value javadoc